# How to Disable Auto-link for TBB

Tags: c++, linker, tbb

When I build my VS project as Debug, it always auto-linked with tbb_debug.lib (which in turn linked with tbb_debug.dll). Is there a way to override this and make tbb.lib linked even for a Debug build?

Comment: may I ask why do you not want the debug lib?

Comment: because my binary is a plug-in, its host has already linked with the release lib of TBB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, are you sure it is 'auto-linked'?

If so, this is done using `#pragma comment( lib, tbb_debug.lib )`. Find where this code is, modify it if it's yours, or else disbale it somehow (either by do not including the file where that code is, or by #defining something that disables this piece code; any sane library writer should provide such a mechanism and it should be documented clearly as well).

If there is no such pragma, the library is linked because it appears in the project settings. Right-click project->Properties->Linker->Input and adjust.

**Edit** thanks to Alexey's comment it seems that you can probably disable TBB's autolinking, as seen in [this header file](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/files/documentation/a00255.html). Defining `__TBB_NO_IMPLICIT_LINKAGE` should do the trick.

Comment: In case of TBB, the macro name is __TBB_NO_IMPLICIT_LINKAGE. However as of now it is not an official, documented feature.

Comment: @AlexeyKukanov great, I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

If the autolinking with `tbb_debug.lib` is accomplished with:

```
#pragma comment( lib, "tbb_debug" )
```

then as explained on [the MSDN documentation page for `pragma comment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> Places a library-search record in the object file. ... The library name follows the default library-search records in the object file; the linker searches for this library just as if you had named it on the command line provided that the library is not specified with [/nodefaultlib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz4da4a%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

You could disable the autolinking via `#pragma comment( lib, "tbb_debug" )` by passing the linker option `/NODEFAULTLIB:tbb_debug.lib`.

However, are you asking because you are receiving a "multiply defined symbols" error (LNK1169) or perhaps LNK4098? If so, it may be that you have `tbb.lib` listed as input to linker for both Debug and Release profiles. You should remove this entry for the Debug profile as the correct library is being automatically linked in.

Comment: I'm asking because, no matter how I change the project file, the build keeps looking for tbb_debug. I think what you pointed out is right and will try as soon as having a chance.