# How to disable TBB when I compile an OpenCV project

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, opencv, tbb

I'm working with OpenCV 2.3.1 on VisualStudio 9 and when I compile my project, I've an error that I do not have the tbb.dll. But I don't need it since it gonna be an Android project in the future.
Someone knows how can I disable the TBB when I compile ?
I've seen the post but it seems not so relevant :s (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565089/how-to-disable-auto-link-for-tbb)

Thx

Answer (score 2):

First you can use cmake-gui (for windows) and re-compile opencv with the following option disable: `-D WITH_TBB (=OFF)` On Windows, this option is maybe called `USE_TBB`.
Second, if you just want to compile your program without using TBB, you need to give the same option if the compiling rule in VS9. I don't now VS so I can just give you the option name.

Comment: But do I really need to recompiled opencv ? (I use the opencv-superpack)

Comment: I you don't want to take advantage of multiple cores in your application you need to recompile opencv without TBB support.

Comment: Yes, that's the point, I want to recompile my project, but not openCV :s

Comment: Recompiling your project without TBB support will not allow you to do threading youself at the application level, that's it.