# Is there a way to disable TBB in openCV?

Tags: opencv, tbb

The C-code(using openCV) I have seems to use TBB and I want to compare the performance
with the one that does not use TBB.

Is there a way to disable TBB?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`setNumThreads(0)`](http://answers.opencv.org/question/15525/disable-cpu-parallelization/), or for a more thorough solution, try recompiling the libraries as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120376/how-to-disable-tbb-when-i-compile-an-opencv-project?rq=1).