# How to disable parallelism in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing, openmp, intel-ipp

I've built OpenCV using Intel IPP, so I suppose that whenever possible it's used (e.g. matrix multiplication).

I want to test the scalability of my parallel application by comparing it with a serial version. In order to do so, when it I do:

```
omp_set_num_threads(1);
cv::setNumThreads(1);
```

However, by monitoring the CPU usage I see that multiple CPUs are still used. Why is that? And how can I force the program execution by using just one CPU?

Comment: It may be using `Intel TBB` - check your config... `getBuildInformation()`

Comment: @MarkSetchell `cv::setNumThreads` should deal with that (as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18478159/is-there-a-way-to-disable-tbb-in-opencv) )

Comment: Do any SO folk know if any OpenCV folk/developers participate on SO and can answer in-depth questions such as this? It has always been a mystery to me as to how to know what optimisations (SIMD, OpenMP, TBB, CUDA) are actually being used in any OpenCV function.... or where anyone tells us typical performance numbers for all the OpenCV functions on any particular hardware? Anyone?

Comment: I think that the only way in this case is to rebuild the whole OpenCV with all parallel options disabled and ipp too. I'm sorry to say this, but if that's the case...well, what a pain in the ass.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I think it all depends on how you compiled opencv. There are different options in the CMake file for the build which control all that.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It is still quite a mystery and sometimes hard to find out. For example usually if you want to know if an algorithm is backed by OpenCL you have to check the source. But not only the find the invocation, but also the exact conditions required for the OpenCL kernel actually to be used. Things like numbers of channels, kernel sizes, border conditions, etc. have to match.

Answer (score 5):

Re-building OpenCV from source with following CMake parameters should works:

```
cmake .. -DWITH_IPP=OFF -DWITH_TBB=OFF -DWITH_OPENMP=OFF -DWITH_PTHREADS_PF=OFF
```

and you will find the macro CV_PARALLEL_FRAMEWORK is not defined to something in [modules/core/src/parallel.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/parallel.cpp#L121) any more:

```
#if defined HAVE_TBB
#  define CV_PARALLEL_FRAMEWORK "tbb"
#elif defined HAVE_HPX
#  define CV_PARALLEL_FRAMEWORK "hpx"
#elif defined HAVE_OPENMP
#  define CV_PARALLEL_FRAMEWORK "openmp"
#elif defined HAVE_GCD
#  define CV_PARALLEL_FRAMEWORK "gcd"
#elif defined WINRT
#  define CV_PARALLEL_FRAMEWORK "winrt-concurrency"
#elif defined HAVE_CONCURRENCY
#  define CV_PARALLEL_FRAMEWORK "ms-concurrency"
#elif defined HAVE_PTHREADS_PF
#  define CV_PARALLEL_FRAMEWORK "pthreads"
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

You can disable it with:

```
cv::setNumThreads(0);
```

> OpenCV will try to set the number of threads for the next parallel region.
> If threads == 0, OpenCV will disable threading optimizations and run all it's
> functions sequentially. Passing threads < 0 will reset threads number to system
> default. This function must be called outside of parallel region.

https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/db/de0/group__core__utils.html

Answer (score 0):

add `ippSetNumThreads(1);` before the first IPP call in your code. This should set number of OpenMP threads in IPP to 1. More info can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/openmp-and-the-intel-ipp-library) in the "Controlling OpenMP Threading in the Intel IPP Primitives" section

Answer (score 0):

Are you using opencv from multi threads ? You have to disable opencv's multi threading from each thread, atleast in my experience with it.

Opencv' parallel_for functions creates multiple threads to distribute the work across.